Putnam 1993 probability question
Two real numbers $x$ and $y$ are chosen at random in the interval $(0, 1)$ with respect to the uniform distribution. What is the probability that the closest integer to $x/y$ is even? Express the answer in
the form $r + s \pi$, where $r$ and $s$ are rational numbers.
I am kinda stuck on this 1993 Putnam problem. I thought of the following: if we assume $y$ to be chosen, then for $x/y$ to be closer to an even number, $0 < x < y/2$ or $3y/2 < x < 5y/2$ or $\ldots$ or (first uneven number lower than $1/y$) $y/2 < x < 1/y \cdot y = 1$. I'm here asking for a little tip helping me further, not the full solution.

Hello! Your approach is correct now you need to integrate your probability over all possible values of $y$ w.r.t the distribution of the $y$.

Draw a square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and shade the areas where $x/y$ rounded is $0,2,4,\ldots$, and then calculate the areas for the initial cases and more generally and sum the series.  You might prefer to use $2x <y < 1$, $\frac25 x < y < \frac23 x$, $\frac29 x < y < \frac27 x$ etc. if you think that way.

Since you are only asking for a tip or hint, I will only furnish this diagram.

